# Mean value theorem and proving inequalities when $f(x) = \ln(\cosh x)$

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to prove that $b-a > \left|\ln\left(\dfrac{\cosh b}{\cosh a}\right)\right|$ using mean value theorem. These are the steps I did so far (continuity and differentiability of $f(x) = \ln{(\cosh{x})}$ are assumed, and $b>a$):
$$ f'(c)=\tanh{c}=\dfrac{\ln\left(\dfrac{\cosh b}{\cosh a}\right)}{b-a} \\
\implies \tanh{c}\cdot(b-a)=\ln\left(\dfrac{\cosh b}{\cosh a}\right) \\ 
\implies |\tanh{c}|\cdot|(b-a)| \geq \left|\ln\left(\dfrac{\cosh b}{\cosh a}\right)\right|$$
At this point I'm stuck. But I saw a similar problem with solution that proceeds from
$$|\cos{c}|\cdot|(b-a)|\geq|\sin{b}-\sin{a}|$$
to
$$1\cdot|(b-a)|\geq|\sin{a}-\sin{b}|$$
I get that $|\sin{b}-\sin{a}| = |\sin{a}-\sin{b}|$. But I don't get exactly why is $|\cos{c}|$ can be expressed as 1 (even though I'm aware that $\cos{c}$ has a maximum value of 1), and yet I feel like I can do this as well with my problem as follows:
$$|\tanh{c}|\cdot|(b-a)| \geq \left|\ln\left(\dfrac{\cosh b}{\cosh a}\right)\right| \\
1\cdot|(b-a)| \geq \left|\ln\left(\dfrac{\cosh b}{\cosh a}\right)\right|$$
Since $b>a$ we can drop the absolute value sign because $b-a$ is always positive and the equality will only happen when $b=a$. So
$$b-a > \left|\ln\left(\dfrac{\cosh b}{\cosh a}\right)\right|$$
I wanna know the reasoning behind why exactly I can make $|\cos{c}=1|$, and what can I do about $|\tanh{c}|$

Comment: Note that $| \tanh(x)| < 1$ for all real numbers $x$.

Comment: They didn't make $\cos(c)$ equal to $1$, but made use of the fact that $\left|\cos(c)\right|\leq 1$. From this inequality and the fact that $|b-a|> 0$, you can multiply  throughout $\left|\cos(c)\right|\leq 1$ by $|b-a|$ to deduce that $|b-a|\cdot\left|\cos(c)\right|\leq |b-a|$. Similar reasoning applies with $\left|\tanh(c)\right|<1$.

Comment: @AlannRosas aight I see what can I do now. thanks!